# How to make child scroll div be treated as main page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am building a web app at which product card expands to fullscreen. But the top bar of browser hiding on scrolldown does not react on this inner scrollable div and reacts only to main page (which is locked when the card is opened). Even the menu button which adds event listener to `window` and is supposed to hide on scrolldown does not do it in card. Moreover, when I decided to use custom scrollbars and packed the main page in a custom div - it stopped reacting on scroll in any situation (f.e. top bar only hides when I scrolled all the way down). How can it be fixed? Maybe a way for it to react to any scroll universally? Thank you in advance!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post your code, please.

Comment: @navigator I don't think I can post something usefull here while not posting the full app. It is more of a general question.

Comment: The browser will only hide the URL bar if the body is scrolled. Your best bet will be to restructure your app to use the root element as your scroll container. Anything else will be a hack and unreliable. If you must, there are some ways around it by using `window.scrollTo` after a small delay to shift the page slightly and cause the URL bar to hide. The issue that this would break the default behavior of the user's OS and likely confuse them.

Comment: @JustinTaddei wow, thank you, very important information indeed! You should've post it as an answer. While the div in which all my app lays is `100vw` I think I will try to call `body` scroll event on it scrolls, maybe that will work (the `body` has nowhere to move). But I agree, that is a bit hacky. Othervise I will try to restructure the app as you said. But I have no idea how to realize my card idea using the root as scroll container. Is it even possible?

Comment: @John I must take back what I said about using `window.scrollTo` as I just tested it and it no longer works (which is expected from a hack). I don't see any reason why you couldn't implement the same card layout using the root. If you update your answer to include the relevant parts of your HTML (just the general structure would help a lot) I could help you figure that out. As for your scrollbars, you'll be better off styling the default ones instead of replacing them. [Here a tutorial about that from css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-styling-scrollbars/)

Comment: @JustinTaddei thank you so much Justin! That was really some valuable information. Thank you very much for your desire to help. But I think further transformation of my app is complex and a bit another question, so I will try to do it myself and won't waste your time with that :) If you will - you can post an answer from your comments here (for example about url bar hiding only on scrolling body) and I will accept the answer, cause the information is just what I needed!

Comment: @John sure thing, I just posted one. Glad I could help in some way. Mobile browser UI is a pain in the butt to deal with lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my earlier comment:

> The browser will only hide the URL bar if the body is scrolled. Your best bet will be to restructure your app to use the root element as your scroll container. Anything else will be a hack and unreliable. If you must, there are some ways around it by using `window.scrollTo` after a small delay to shift the page slightly and cause the URL bar to hide. The issue that this would break the default behavior of the user's OS and likely confuse them.

@John's comment:

> @JustinTaddei wow, thank you, very important information indeed! You should've post it as an answer. While the div in which all my app lays is 100vw I think I will try to call body scroll event on it scrolls, maybe that will work (the body has nowhere to move). But I agree, that is a bit hacky. Othervise I will try to restructure the app as you said. But I have no idea how to realize my card idea using the root as scroll container. Is it even possible?

I must take back what I said about using `window.scrollTo` as I just tested it and it no longer seems to works (which is expected from a hack). I don't see any reason why you couldn't implement the same card layout using the root element.

As for the scrollbars, you'll be better off styling the default ones instead of replacing them. [Here a tutorial about that from css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-styling-scrollbars/)